# Error in setting the IP configuration properties of mini port adapter

Tags: windows, kernel, driver, wdk, ndis

I am working on developing an intermediate NDIS driver. It is actually a load balancing driver which I am working on. There is one strange issue which I am getting while changing the miniport properties. After installing the driver, when I try to change the IP address of the miniport in its properties page. It is taking too long and goes to not responding state. IP configuration changes are not getting applied and also I am not able to access the miniport property page after the not responding state. This behavior is so weird that I am not able to figure out what is the root cause.

Can anyone here help in this issue?

I am not getting any error message or error code. I tried to set the IP configuration through command prompt also and got the same behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Something is probably leaked in kernel mode.  Check for stuck NBLs with `!ndiskd.pendingnbls` or stuck OIDs with `!ndiskd.oid`.  Look for threads that are stuck calling into your driver with `!stacks 2 ndis!`.

Changing the IP address can incidentally result in halting and re-initializing your NIC driver.  Some types of leaks don't show up until the driver is unloaded.